# Change WooCommerce product "Select options" add to cart button text

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I would need to change "Select Options" text for variable products in my WooCommerce store. Please check the screenshot below, so you can see what I am talking about.

Preview of the button with select options text:

[image]

I tried to use the following code, but my WordPress page crashed after I added it to functions.php file. I did change 'Options' for a new text for this button. I am not sure if I had to edit this part of code.

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_dropdown_variation_attribute_options_args', 'custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 10, 2);
 
function custom_woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text($args){ 
    $args['show_option_none'] = __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' ); 
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Welcome! Part of the problem is in your `add_filter` you have the number `2`, which means the function you are using to change the output is expecting 2 parameters passed. You only have one `$args`. You can change the `2` to a `1` or pass the other parameter to your function that the filter is expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You are not using the right hook for that. Instead, use the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_add_to_cart_text', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button_text', 20, 2 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button_text( $text, $product ) {
    if ( $product->is_type( 'variable' ) && $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        $text = __( 'Options', 'woocommerce' );
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

---

##### Alternative addition:

If it doesn't work, try the following instead:

```php
add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_some_woocommerce_strings', 10, 3 );
function change_some_woocommerce_strings( $translate_text, $original_text, $domain ) {
    global $woocommerce_loop;

    if ( isset($woocommerce_loop['is_paginated']) 
    && ! empty($woocommerce_loop['is_paginated'])
    && strtolower($original_text) === strtolower('Select options') ) {
        $translate_text = __('Options', $domain );
    }
    return $translate_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I added this code to function.php, the page didn't crash but "select options" text didn't change. You can see it here - https://www.peciatkyonline.sk/obchod/

Comment: @Pixsector-com I have added an addition code alternative… Try it…

Comment: Thank you again. Sadly, the code didn't work. I added it to function.php and
edited this part:  $translate_text = __('KUPIT', $domain ); but nothing happend. 

I recently installed this plugin "WooCommerce Product Options from Barn2" Its quite simple plugin with not many options. Can this plugin blocking your code?

Comment: @Pixsector-com I don't use Barn2 plugins as they are mostly commercial, kind of closed and doesn't work well with some other plugins or some custom code. To see if the plugin is making trouble, try to deactivate it to see what happens.

Comment: Your code is working! I deactived and then activated the Barn2 plugin and the "Select Options" text in buttons changed. 

The only problem is that your code didnt work for woocommerce products added on the page through Gutenberg block
https://www.peciatkyonline.sk/