Replace Loop Add to cart button with a button linked to the product and different text based on categories
In WooCommerce I changed "Add to cart button" to "View product" on shop page with the following:
// First, remove Add to Cart Button
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'my_remove_add_to_cart', 99 );
function my_remove_add_to_cart() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 );    
}

// Second, add View Product Button
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_view_product_button', 10 );
function custom_view_product_button() {
    global $product;
    $link = $product->get_permalink();
    echo '<a href="' . $link . '" class="button addtocartbutton">View product</a>';
}  

But also I need different text on "View product" button for different categories.
I need 5 different texts for 5 different categories on "View product" button on shop page only (on single product page, there should stay "add to cart button".
I used this code for change to View product button, but I dont know how to display a different "View product" text for different product categories.
So somehow add to this code different "View product" text for 5 different categories on shop page.
Category 1 -> View product text 1
Category 2 -> View product text 2
etc

There is a much better to way to get this using woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link filter hook… In the answer below, the loop add to cart button is changed to a button linked to the product, displaying a different text in the button based on the assigned product category.

Instead of removing add to cart button and replace it with a custom button, you can use woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link filter hook.
The button text will be different depending on the product categories.
As you doesn't use it, you can also disable Ajax add to cart (in WooCommerce settings):

Now in the first function below, you will define your product categories term Id(s), name(s) or slug(s) and for each category(ies), the corresponding text to be displayed in the button. You can define one or multiple category terms for each text.
The code:
// Settings function: Define for each categories, the corresponding button text to display
function get_category_button_text() {
    return array(
        array(
            'terms' => array('hoodies', 'pants'), // Accept multiple categories term Ids, term slugs or term names
            'text' => __('Button Text 1', 'woocommerce') // Button text
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('tshirts', 'shirts'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 2', 'woocommerce')
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('accessories'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 3', 'woocommerce')
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('music', 'video'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 4', 'woocommerce')
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('furniture'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 5', 'woocommerce')
        ),
    );
}

// Replace Loop Add to Cart with a button linked to the product
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'replacing_add_to_cart_button', 1000, 2 );
function replacing_add_to_cart_button( $button, $product  ) {
    $taxonomy    = 'product_cat';
    $product_id  = $product->get_id();
    $button_text = __('View product', 'woocommerce'); // The default text

    // Loop through defined category terms / text pairs
    foreach( get_category_button_text() as $values ) {
        if ( has_term($values['terms'], $taxonomy, $product_id ) ) {
            $button_text = $values['text'];
            break;
        } 
    }
    return sprintf('<a href="%s" class="button addtocartbutton">%s</a>', $product->get_permalink(), $button_text );
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Code alternative:
You can also use the following alternative (similar):
// Settings function: Define for each categories, the corresponding button text to display
function get_category_button_text() {
    return array(
        array(
            'terms' => array('hoodies', 'Hoodtwo', 'pants'), // Accept multiple categories term Ids, term slugs or term names
            'text' => __('Button Text 1', 'woocommerce') // Button text
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('tshirts', 'shirts'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 2', 'woocommerce')
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('accessories'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 3', 'woocommerce')
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('music', 'video'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 4', 'woocommerce')
        ),
        array(
            'terms' => array('furniture'), 
            'text' => __('Button Text 5', 'woocommerce')
        ),
    );
}

// Replace Loop Add to Cart with a button linked to the product
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'replace_loop_add_to_cart_button', 999 );
function replace_loop_add_to_cart_button() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10 ); 
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'custom_loop_button_replacement', 10 );
}

// Custom button
function custom_loop_button_replacement() {
    global $product;

    $taxonomy    = 'product_cat';
    $product_id  = $product->get_id();
    $button_text = __('View product', 'woocommerce'); // The default text

    // Loop through defined category terms / text pairs
    foreach( get_category_button_text() as $values ) {
        if ( has_term($values['terms'], $taxonomy, $product_id ) ) {
            $button_text = $values['text'];
            break;
        } 
    }
    printf('<a href="%s" class="button addtocartbutton">%s</a>', $product->get_permalink(), $button_text );
}

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and also works.

Amazing! Thank you a lot!!
It works exactly what I needed and try to solve for hours!
:)
I need just one thing for that. Your code works perfectly for single product, but it doesnt work for products with variations - then is on the button text "Select option".
I have in categories single products and with variations as well, and need there same custom text on the button.

Sorry but the code is tested and works with simple and variable products too.

With your code above I still had there "Select option" with variable product. But when I added to functions.php another your code from here "Alternative addition" on this page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77941717/change-woocommerce-product-select-options-add-to-cart-button-text
then it works. I made some compromise to need custom text only for single products, and for variable products I have one general text for all.

This behavior is related might be related to other code from your theme or a third party plugin. With pure WooCommerce on Storefront theme (without other 3rd party plugins that can interact), there is no such problem... I have added an addition to my answer, an alternative way that should work for you... Try it.

Now it works! Thanks! I have Hello theme from Elementor and page builder Elementor as well, and also some other code for show stock and for hide price for some categories on archive page, and also third party plugin for quantity measurement calculator for some products. Some mystery. Anyway now it works! :)
